# how to find the particular integral of the following expression?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

The question appeared in the university examination.

$$(D^2-D-2)y=2*\log x+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}$$

I did the usual procedure that is to $\frac{1}{F(D)}Q=P.I$

where Q is the function of x only

The formula for the manipulation is 
$$P.I=\frac{e^{mx}}{e^{mx}}*\frac{1}{F(D-m)}dxQ$$
$$P.I=e^{mx}*e^{-mx}\frac{1}{F(D-m)}Qdx$$
$$P.I=e^{mx}\int{e^{-mx}Qdx}$$

The above formula is obtained to make the D-m nullified to an integration by replacing the D by D+m. which is an identity and can be applied. Vice versa is also possible.

By manipulation we get
$$P.I=\frac{-1}{3}e^{-x}\int{e^x[2\log x+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}]dx}+\frac{1}{3}e^{2x}\int{e^{-2x}[2\log x+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}]dx}$$
But I am having problem to integrate the following expression, any guidance will be appreciated. I have tried to use the substitution method but there is no factor that is replacing the dx. 
I have previously asked the answer to the first part of the equation and got the answer but i Want to know the answer to the second term that is 
$$I_2=\frac{1}{3}e^{2x}\int{e^{-2x}[2\log x+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}]dx}$$

Comment: I will try it thanks, but the university wants us to use this method sans the variation of parameters. so i need the solution using this method only.@Moo